# Differential operator- Equality

Tags: fourier-analysis, distribution-theory

Suppose that  $L$ is a linear differential operator such that $Lu(x)=f(x)$.

[image]

Why does the following equality hold?

$$L \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \hat{y}(\omega) e^{i \omega t} d \omega=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} L(-i \omega) \hat{y}(\omega) e^{i \omega t} d \omega $$

Comment: The $L$ would not act on $-i\omega$. It would act on the functions of $t$, provided you are allowed to interchange integration and the differential operator.

Comment: So you mean that it is wrong? @TrialAndError $$$$
I found it in wikipedia where they describe how to find the fundamental solution of an equation, using the Fourier-transform.

Comment: Yes, I think it's wrong. If $L$ acts on functions of $t$ as the application on the left would suggest, then $L$ should act on functions of $t$ on the right. At a bare minimum, the notation is lousy.

Comment: The notation is lousy.

Answer (score 0):

I think the result presumes that $L$ is a linear constant coefficient differential operator.  When applied to $-i\omega$, $L$ appears to be treated as a polynomial in $-i\omega$, so that for example if $L=ad^2/dx^2+bd/dx+c$ we have $L(-i\omega)=a(-i\omega)^2+b(-i\omega)+c$.

In one dimension, we read in Rudin *Real and Complex Analysis* (2nd edition) 9.2(f) that if $f, g\in L^1$, $g(x)=-ixf(x)$, then $\hat{f}$ is differentiable and $\hat{f}{}'=\hat{g}$. If in the equation that appears in the question we have $L=d/dx$, $f=\hat{y}$, and plug in the definition of Fourier transform and the convention that for such $L$ we have $L(-i\omega)=-i\omega$, it reduces to the result just quoted.  By iteration we get the equation for $L=d^n/dx^n$ (using a convention whereby $L(-i\omega)=(-i\omega)^n$ in that case), and by linearity for all linear constant coefficient differential operators.

A different version of the result, in $n$ dimensions, appears to be found in Rudin *Functional Analysis* 7.4(c).  However, there we have instead of $L$ a polynomial $P$ and the differential operators $P(D)$ and $P(-D)$.  This is much better notation in my humble opinion.

Comment: I want to show using the fourier transform that the fundamental solution of $\frac{\partial{E}}{\partial{t}}-a^2 \Delta E=\delta(t,x), x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is given by $E(t,x)=\frac{H(t)}{(2a \sqrt{\pi t})^n} e^{-\frac{|x|^2}{4a^2 t}}$. $$$$
So we have:


$$\frac{1}{(2 \pi)^n} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \widehat{\phi(\xi)} e^{i x  \xi} d \xi=\phi(x)=\frac{\partial{E}}{\partial{t}}-a^2 \Delta E=\left( \frac{\partial}{\partial t}-a^2 \Delta \right)E=\left( \frac{\partial}{\partial t}-a^2 \Delta \right) \frac{1}{(2 \pi)^n} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \hat{E}(\xi) e^{ix \xi} d \xi$$

Comment: So how can we continue now?

Comment: I don't know.  I don't know what $H$ or $\phi$ are either.  Perhaps $\phi$ is a test function for proving the equality of two distributions, but in that case, shouldn't it be a function of $(t,x)$ since you have $\delta(t,x)$ on the right hand side?

Comment: $H$ is the Heaviside function, $\phi$ is a test function.  Oh yes, it should be a function of two variables. @ForgotALot